# Sort strings by the first N characters

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a text file with lines like this:

```
2010-02-18 11:46:46.1287 bla
2010-02-18 11:46:46.1333 foo
2010-02-18 11:46:46.1333 bar
2010-02-18 11:46:46.1467 bla
```

A simple sort would swap lines 2 and 3 (bar comes before foo), but I would like to keep lines (that have the same date/time) in their original order.

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sorted(array, key=lambda x:x[:24])
```

Example:

```
>>> a = ["wxyz", "abce", "abcd", "bcde"]
>>> sorted(a)
['abcd', 'abce', 'bcde', 'wxyz']
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[:3])
['abce', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'wxyz']
```

Comment: Note that this sorts the the date/time as a string. That happens to work in this case. Otherwise you might need to use a smarter key function which actually parses the date/time.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in sort is stable, so you the effectively-equal values stay in order by default.

```
import operator

with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    sorted_lines = sorted(f, key=operator.itemgetter(slice(0, 24)))
```

At this point `sorted_lines` will be a list of the sorted lines. To replace the old file, make a new file, call `new_file.writelines(sorted_lines)`, then move the new file over the old one.

Comment: `s/slice(24, None)/slice(0, 24)/`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, Thanks, I misread the question (and thought it conflicted with the title). Also, your regex is wrong. ;)