# How to sort by last x characters only with varying length strings?

Tags: python

Say my list looks like this

['abda01.txt', 'fdafe10.txt', 'ytn05.txt', 'a02.txt' ]

And I want to sort by the last 6 characters only, so the result looks like this

['abda01.txt', 'a02.txt', 'ytn05.txt', 'fdafe10.txt']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort strings by the first N characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289870/sort-strings-by-the-first-n-characters). Adopting this to the last N characters should be trivial if you know [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list.sort(key = lambda x : x[-6:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sorted(files, key=lambda x: (x[-7:]))
```