# String sorting of a class with a string in it

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have this class called Suffix():

```
class Suffix:
    def __init__(self, index, suffix):
        self.index = index #int
        self.suffix = suffix #string
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.index},{self.suffix})'
```

I have a list with a bunch of instances from this class called sa = [suffix list]

Now I want to sort sa alphabetically according to the first 36 characters of the suffix string of the suffix.

I found [Sort strings by the first N characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289870/sort-strings-by-the-first-n-characters) that showed me

```
sorted(array, key=lambda x:x[:24])
```

But is there a way to implement this without putting all my suffixes into a seperate array, that would defeat my purpose.

Comment: That would be something like `key=lambda x: x.suffix[:36]`.

Comment: it still gives me the error of  'list' object has no attribute 'suffix'. This is the code:
sa_array = np.asarray(sa)
sa_array_flat = sa_array.flatten() #flattened by default in row-major ("C"-style)
sa_sorted = sorted(sa_array_flat, key=lambda x: x.suffix[:36])

I flattened the array because I figures it might be that, but no luck

Comment: You have somehow ended up with an array of lists, rather than an array of `Suffix` instances.  I'm not sure why numpy is involved here at all, that's primarily useful with numeric arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__eq__`, `__le__`, `__ge__`, `__ne__`
to use the first 36 characters you can use the built is sort function of python on your custom